# Unable to share private google hangout app

Tags: oauth, google-hangouts

While trying to share a private hangout app, I am getting the following error:

`You need to create an OAuth client ID in the Developer Console before you can share this app.`

In the Google Developers Console, I went to New Credentials > Help Me Choose, and selected:

1. Google+ Hangouts API
2. Web browser (Javascript)

This led me to create a browser key, which I did.

This does not fix the original error though. I also tried New Credentials > OAuth client ID > Web Application, but this requires an Authorized redirect URI.

Since the hangout app itself consists of a single xml file, it feels a bit excessive needing to write a web application to handle the oauth callback.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Help Me Choose creates the wrong credentials for a Hangout App.

Instead, this worked for me:

1. Click New Credentials > OAuth client ID.
2. Select Web Application.
3. Choose a Name for the Client ID, but leave the other two fields blank (Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs).
4. Click [Create] and [OK].
5. Start a Google Hangout and open your app.
6. This will result in **Error: invalid_client**.
7. Click Request Details.
8. Find origin= and copy the value. It should look something like this: https://*end-a-hangout-opensocial.googleusercontent.com.
9. Go back to the Developers Console and open the OAuth Client ID created above.
10. Enter the origin value in the Authorized JavaScript origins field.
11. Click [Save].
12. Refresh the Hangout and re-open your hangout app.